# Why doesn't my applet asks me for permission, instead throws an AccessControlException?

Tags: java, applet

Why doesn't my Java Applet ask me for permission to start when I open HTML page with it on my localhost?

What is more, the applet starts but it cannot do anything. One of its duties is to connect with a webpage. But it doesn't. In console I can read:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.onet.pl:80 connect,resolve)

I guess there is a problem with the security settings of my Java.

Comment: The "same-origin" policy means that untrusted code can only access the host it came from (unless the target host contains an appropriate `crossdomain.xml` file).

Answer (score 0):

It's some time since I programmed my last Applet, but I think you probably need to sign your jars.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I want my applet works just like any other applet from the web. I click "Run" when Java ask me for permission and applet starts. But in my case Java doesn't ask me for  permission when I try to launch from localhost in my borwser.

Comment: @Leez: I think he understood your request. Unless your applet is signed, you can't have it request additional permissions!

Answer (score 0):

The general policy for untrusted (i.e. not signed) applets is that they are only allowed (network-wise) to connect to the server they are loaded from. For applets loaded locally from the file system, this means they can connect localhost.

Asking the user for permission will only occur if either the applet is signed (but then the user gives permission for everything, if there is not a special security policy file) or the applet uses the JNLP functions to request some access (but this is only for local access) - for this, you would need the latest plugin (1.6.0_10 or later).

As Tom mentioned, a remote server can permit applets (and other dynamic web-content like JavaScript, Flash and so on) from other sites to access his server with a [cross domain policy file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html). I'm not sure from which version on the Java plugin implements this, though.